# Error : credit_card_form is deprecated since version 2.6! Use > WC_Payment_Gateway_CC->form instead

Tags: wordpress, class, woocommerce, credit-card

I am using this code to generate the credit card form but it throws a notice that

> credit_card_form is deprecated since version 2.6! Use
>   WC_Payment_Gateway_CC->form instead.

```
public function payment_fields() {
          $this->credit_card_form();
        }
```

So how do i access that class as i am currently extending the `WC_Payment_Gateway`?

```
class GGOwl_Woo extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by deprecated method notice itself, you should use `WC_Payment_Gateway_CC` instead.
You can use similar code yourself as used in `WC_Payment_Gateway::credit_card_form`. So you can replace `$this->credit_card_form()` with following:

```
$cc_form           = new WC_Payment_Gateway_CC();
$cc_form->id       = $this->id;
$cc_form->supports = $this->supports;
$cc_form->form();
```

This is just a workaround, you should actually extend your class from `WC_Payment_Gateway_CC`.

Comment: thank you ..i am trying to figure out how to use the form values? any reference

Comment: You can extend your class with `WC_Payment_Gateway_CC` which itself is subclass of `WC_Payment_Gateway`, so with some addition similar API is available to you. You can see source code of the class to learn more:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.4/includes/gateways/class-wc-payment-gateway-cc.php